# Ubuntu won't install grub to sdb even though it should. (UEFI)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, hard-drive

I tried installing Ubuntu 20.04.1 on my laptop today. I used the "use the entire drive" option and told it to install to sdb (a 240 GB Kingston SSD) but it decided to install grub to sda instead, even though the documentation says:

> Installation Options (LiveCD)
>
> Using the Entire Drive ( "Erase disk and
> install Ubuntu" ): Install on entire drive: The user should select a
> drive on which Ubuntu and GRUB 2 will be installed. GRUB 2 will
> overwrite the drive's boot information and place the GRUB 2 files in
> the appropriate locations.

Is this a bug? Is there any easy workaround that I could use?

The end result I desire would be two clean and self-contained drives that don't need each other to boot.

Comment: Option only works with BIOS installs. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379
Others suggest disconnecting other drives physically or logically in UEFI settings, so install drive is first drive.
Or removing boot flag/esp flag from first drive, so only ESP is install drive. (I have not had that work, but others have.)
Or if you have ESP on second or external drive, you can just reinstall grub, either manually or using Boot-Repair's advanced mode & full reinstall to correct drive.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this. The only way I achieved what I wanted (boot where I wanted it) was to install Ubuntu Server which is much more flexible as to where boot partition is and then installed the necessary GUI/desktop afterwards.